# python scrapy linkextractor deny regex

Tags: python, regex, scrapy, regex-negation

i am trying to build a sitemap of my ecommerce website with links to all my individual products. i am using python to extract the product links of my website

the rule that i have in place is :

```
extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=('\/(?!product)\/'))
rules = (
    Rule(extractor,callback='parse_links',follow=True),
)
```

which should give me all the links which have 'product' in them (these are my product urls)

Problem: it is not extracting any links from my base url. could you tell me what regular expression pattern do i need to use for that ?

note: if i use the regex ('/product/'), it gives me all the links on the website, irrespective whether it has the text 'product' in it or not.

Comment: Could you provide a valid start url please for testing please?

Comment: If you want to match URLs that contain "product" it's easier to use the `allow` parameter: `extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('product', ))` (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html)